# URL rewriting weird error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

These are the rewrite rules that I'm having problems with.

```
# Pretty URLs
RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ /article?query=$1

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([/A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /$1.php
```

This is the URL that i'm trying to build

```
http://www.example.com/article/392-demolition
```

When I debug I found out that the rewriterules are actually sending the request to

```
http://www.example.com/article.php?query=392-demolition.php
```

If I remove the slash from the second rule or add [R] to the first rule everything works fine. Can anyone explain why or what is the mistake here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Pretty URLs
RewriteRule ^article/(.+)$ /article?query=$1 [NC,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls (with test)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

use a simple re-write :

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?query=$1 [L]
```